# Datastax Java API to get tablestats and histogram

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to know the Java API equivalents for the following commands, please let me know if there are any.

```
$NODETOOL netstats       
$NODETOOL tpstats        
$NODETOOL describecluster 
$NODETOOL compactionstats
$NODETOOL proxyhistograms
$NODETOOL tablestats
$NODETOOL tablehistograms
```

I have searched datastax API and google, but not able to find any such thing.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently adding nodetool functionalities to our [diagnostics](https://github.com/smartcat-labs/cassandra-diagnostics) library. If you want to do it yourself, your best bet is to wrap Cassandra's NodeProbe class and query what you want yourself. If you don't want to go typed you can query mxbeans over JMX.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in nodetool is exposed via JMX and can be accessed with the [JRE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html) standard lib, for example you can list all the mbeans:

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.remote.*;
...

JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:7199");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

for (ObjectInstance i : mbsc.queryMBeans(new ObjectName("org.apache.cassandra.metrics:*"), null)) {
    System.out.println(i.getObjectName());
}
```

nodetool just organizes them a bit for you. You can read a bit on the metrics and how they are exposed at http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html and if trying to send metrics to your own tooling consider using the [reporter interface](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#metric-reporters).